# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmemcached_gem

Tags: ruby, memcached

While trying to make the memcached gem, i am getting the following error:

```
*linking shared-object rlibmemcached.so
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-memcached/akamai/ruby-memcached/memcached-1.8.0/ext/lib/libmemcached_gem.a when searching for -lmemcached_gem
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /ghostcache/nightly_build/components/ruby-memcached/akamai/ruby-memcached/memcached-1.8.0/ext/lib/libmemcached_gem.a when searching for -lmemcached_gem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmemcached_gem
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [rlibmemcached.so] Error 1*
```

Looks like there is some platform issue. The `libmemcached_gem`.a library does exist in that path. I tried building by passing `-m32` and `-m64`, but it fails for the same reason.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: which os you are using ?

Comment: When you installed that gem, it would have tried to compile this C extension part. Was that part successful? Try removing the gem, reinstalling and read the output carefully.

Comment: Using Ubuntu. I was trying to use the bundle that was already compiled on macOS on a ubuntu machine, which is why this problem. I directly used the bundle from the internet and it is working fine now. Thank you.